# Sort Pandas columns by number of unique groups

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I'm attempting to sort a section of the categorical data from the kaggle [Housing Prices](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data) dataset. I'm attempting to sort the columns by the number of unique categories. To avoid cluttering the question, I've included a small section of the dataframe (80 total columns) to demonstrate the problem.

```
    LotConfig    Street    MSZoning
0   Inside       Pave      RL
1   FR2          Pave      RL
2   Corner       Grvl      RL
```

I'm aiming to sort the columns to achieve the following result.

```
    MSZoning    Street    LotConfig    
0   RL          Pave      Inside       
1   RL          Pave      FR2          
2   RL          Grvl      Corner
```

I'm currently using the following code.

```
sorted_categories =  sorted(df.columns, key = lambda col: df[col].nunique())
df = df[sorted_categories]
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem? Am I missing a pandas method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `nunique` directly and index your initial DataFrame using the result:

```
u = df.nunique().sort_values().index
df[u]
```

```
  MSZoning Street LotConfig
0       RL   Pave    Inside
1       RL   Pave       FR2
2       RL   Grvl    Corner
```

---

`df.nunique()` will return a Series of unique values per column.

```
>>> df.nunique()
LotConfig    3
Street       2
MSZoning     1
dtype: int64
```

---

***However***, on your small example, your approach is actually faster than mine, albeit a bit more verbose.  I would test this on your actual DataFrame, since your method isn't incorrect, and if it improves performance, I would go with that instead.  I believe my method should be faster on a large frame since it avoids calling `nunique` many times.

Comment: So for the actual DataFrame, the `sorted(code)` method takes `4.5 ms ± 42 µs per loop` and `df.nunique().sort_values().index` takes `6.33 ms ± 51.5 µs per loop`. I wondered how this would scale as you mentioned. Shall I modify my question with the results for a much larger DataFrame? There isn't enough space in the comment box. Without access to a similar categorical DataFrame, I just repeated the existing DataFrame and performed the same operation